# Bootstrap Multiple Item Carousel and normal Carousel inside a single page asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this *6 item multiple carousel* as shown in http://www.bootply.com/IQ5RPxXjZ9 and a *normal 1 item carousel* inside a same page.  But because of the code below, the normal carousel doesn't slide properly from 1 image to another.

```
@media (min-width: 992px ) {

    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -16.7%; }  
}
```

how to make both sliders to work properly inside this same page?

Answer (score 0):

2your bootply has only 1 slider, but in any case, to apply different CSS for both sliders, they need to have different ID and then you do like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px ) {

    #slider1 .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
    #slider1 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
    #slider1 .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -16.7%; }  
    #slider2 .carousel-inner .active.left { left: 0; }
    #slider2 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  0; }
    #slider2 .carousel-inner .prev        { left: 0; }  
}
```

Please note that left:0 might be replaced by anything, and you might add different Styling, just adding it as an example since as I said, you have only one slider

Comment: By "different ID" you meant 'div ID' right. If it is, your solution doesn't work. Any ideas?